# How to format DataGrid columns with for loop

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datagrid, formatting

I want to format my DataGrid columns but starting from 1 to infinity.
I want to do it with for loop.

Here is my code that doesn't work.

```
for (int v = 1; v < 99999; v++)
{
    metroGrid1.Columns[v].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n";
}
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: What does “doesn’t work” mean?

Comment: It doesn't affect anything.

Comment: What is the data type in that cell?

Comment: Infinity? I don't think there is any DataGrid which has infinite columns. How many columns on earth?

Comment: @ojlovecd I think even 99999 is quite huge

Comment: It is an example guys chill.

Comment: @John It's a number but I want to format these number "n" or "N2" style.

Comment: @ÖzgünErdemCeylan can't you just define default cell style for the whole grid instead of row by row? [`metroGrid1.DefaultCellStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @Rafalon I don't want to format 0th column.

Comment: What about formatting grid's default cell style, then formatting 0th column back specifically?

Comment: @Rafalon You are genius. I can try it but how can I format 0th column to short date string?

Comment: Okay I did it. Can you answer my question with this comment so I can verify your answer and everybody can see it.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the first column format to differ from all other columns, you could set a default cell value to the whole grid, then format the first column specifically.

Something like (for example):

```
metroGrid1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
metroGrid1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"; // short date string
```